# Can I find my fathers war history

Tags: military-records

My father served in North Africa before becoming a prisoner of war and was sent to the San Francisco Area.

Comment: Hi, Mike, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your question could be improved by telling us what you have already tried to do to find this information. Showing research effort helps you because it helps you organize your own findings, and it helps us because we have a clearer picture of where you are starting from. I have edited out the part where you signed your name because the site signs Qs and As with your user card.  You can learn more about how the site works by reading the [help] or our companion [meta].  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

The US National Archives' Know Your Records Program did a presentation [Provost Marshal General & Enemy Prisoners of War Held in the U.S. during World War II (2023 Sept 13)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytgSD1nC_uo) which can be viewed on NARA's YouTube Channel. The [handout](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbU55UzFsaVZwQnpnbEtma01lcWw3QUtsVkx4Z3xBQ3Jtc0tsM0kzOWZRSUZIOFZvLWFNSWhIc0pTT202VFZtS0FqZUk0Y2tHWldVOVBNczlobkJPeXpKbGdMRWR3UjdFTzNaSUIyM3hnUGtpa20zTWk4d0FFc2laOXp6Vjlrak9qVU4waE9JZDJ0NEl6Q1FlSUt5SQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.archives.gov%2Ffiles%2Fcalendar%2Fknow-your-records%2Fhandouts-presentations%2F2023-09-13-salyer-handout.pdf&v=ytgSD1nC_uo) and [presentation slides](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbGdiSGZEMm1jZUxXaTNfaGRKZS1QTm13X3p6d3xBQ3Jtc0tuS05TcF9WS2lZN3BUREwwWk9tWlNLTWppWDJzSlFUX29ydjUwYWVYRFhKUGdCOXY4Y2NGbDZKcUNZdGhVUjJPY0FwMTZUdFNtVmlpLWJMbjVqTEdVOW44SjE1SVR3ZFdWNUduV29BckJRVmxOVzVSSQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.archives.gov%2Ffiles%2Fcalendar%2Fknow-your-records%2Fhandouts-presentations%2F2023-09-13-salyer-presentation.pdf&v=ytgSD1nC_uo) are available for download.

> During World War II, the United States established hundreds of
> prisoner of war (POW or PW) camps, which held an estimated 425,000
> German, Italian, and Japanese prisoners. Archivist Rachael Salyer will
> discuss the records of these camps created by the Office of the
> Provost Marshal General (OPMG). She will provide an overview of their
> establishment and construction, and then will focus on how and where
> to locate records related to specific camps. Finally, she will also
> provide suggestions for how to begin researching individual prisoners,
> as well as camp staff and assigned units.